# How does order of prepositional phrases effect semantics?

Tags: linguistic-typology, word-order, information-structure, focus, topic-comment

I was discussing the semantics difference when switching prepositional objects in the following sentences with a German native:

> , damit die Eltern auf ihre Kinder über CCTV aufpassen können,

> damit die Eltern über CCTV auf ihre Kinder aufpassen können

By swap of the prepositional phrases "ueber CCTV" and "auf ihre Kinder"  from first to second, we have a change in meaning from "CCTV established, now we can watch children" to "we can watch children, and now do it with CCTV".

I found this quite interesting how "what is established" changes as we switch phrases. Is there a general theory for how this works in a general language?/ Are there categorizations of languages based on how semantics change when switching prepositional objects?

Answer (score 1):

For the larger picture: Yes there are categorisations of languages based on [information structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_structure).

The most traditional terminology would call the two roles [theme and rheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment), more modern terminology uses *topic and comment*, *focus and background*, and *given—new*.

In linguistic typology, one classifies some languages as [topic prominent languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic-prominent_language) where the syntactical marking of topic and focus is emphasised.